# Failed to parse the WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I am trying to generate src from wsdl using following tutorial but getting exception while wsimport.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsgen-tool-example/

> wsimport -keep -verbose
>   http://localhost:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService?wsdl

Getting following error :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin>wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService?wsdl
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://localhost:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService?wsdl

Failed to read the WSDL document: http://localhost:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.


        Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

ServerInfoService?wsdl

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.mkyong.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="ServerInfoService" targetNamespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://ws.mkyong.com/" targetNamespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/">
  <xsd:complexType name="getIpAddressResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="getIpAddress"/>
  <xsd:element name="getIpAddressResponse" type="ns0:getIpAddressResponse"/>
  <xsd:element name="getIpAddress" type="ns0:getIpAddress"/>
</xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getIpAddress">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getIpAddress" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getIpAddressResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getIpAddressResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServerInfo">
        <wsdl:operation name="getIpAddress">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getIpAddress" name="getIpAddress"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getIpAddressResponse" name="getIpAddressResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServerInfoServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ServerInfo">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getIpAddress">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="getIpAddress">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getIpAddressResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ServerInfoService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:ServerInfoServiceSoapBinding" name="ARMServicePortTypeImplPort">
            <soap:address location="http://10.19.9.92:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you access the wsdl from browser first? Seems like invoking the url is failing because of timeout. May be proxy is set in your environment which is not bypassing localhost?

Comment: yes it is accessible from browser. with URL : http://localhost:7001/poc-war/ServerInfoService?wsdl

Comment: And also from command promopt using wget or something like that? Why i am saying is because 504 is clear gatway error. Could it be importing schema from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a networking issue. You could open the wsdl in your browser copy and paste the text into a new .wsdl file and regenerate it from the hard drive URL vs a network URL.

I have had times where network security has made it impossible for me to reach WSDL's using some development tools so keeping a copy locally can work. I admit it is a work around at best but 502 is not easy to troubleshoot without a lot more information.